24.04 fails to start after upgrade from 22.04
Lambda user here.
On iMac21 (2013) ubuntu 20 to 22 happily. Now intended to upgrade to 24.
After a normal course of installation of 24.04, it announced it was going to make a first full restart.
Heard the gong and then the ubuntu screen appeared with the wheel turning.
And nothing else ever happened. I cannot access anything anymore, no keyboard, just de mouse is working.
Can anybody recommend how to release this process or go back to 22.04 ?
